# Trying to create a stacked bar chart of the top 10 issues per month

Tags: python, pandas

I have a stacked series that looks like the following (date is represented as just a month integer):

```
date  issues        size                        
1     issue1        1
      issue2        2
      issue3        1
      issue4        6
      issue5        1
...
8     issue1        1
      issue2        2
      issue3        1
      issue4        6
      issue5        1
```

I can create the stacked bar chart by just graphing with

```
series.unstack().fillna(0)
```

but I want to limit the number of issues to only the top 10 by size per date, as there are currently over 100. This is the part I cannot figure out. Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

Here is what my original DataFrame looks like for more clarity.

```
          date  issues
0            1  issue1 
1            1  issue2 
2            1  issue3 
3            1  issue1
4            1  issue3 
5            2  issue1 
6            2  issue2 
7            2  issue3
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return just the top-sized objects wrt size by [applying to each group](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#flexible-apply) a [sort](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html) and then [head](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.head.html).
Here we look at just the top two:

```
In [11]: top2_by_date = df.groupby('date').apply(lambda x:  x.sort('size', ascending=False).head(2))

In [12]: top2_by_date
Out[12]: 
        date  issues  size
date                      
1    3     1  issue4     6
     1     1  issue2     2
8    8     8  issue4     6
     6     8  issue2     2
```

*Annoying we have date in the index [(`as_index=False` doesn't stop this](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/4649), [for now](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/4670)).*

```
In [13]: top2_by_date.index =  top2_by_date.index.droplevel(0)

In [14]: top2_by_date
Out[14]: 
   date  issues  size
3     1  issue4     6
1     1  issue2     2
8     8  issue4     6
6     8  issue2     2
```

Using the original data (without the size column, you can do this in one pass) with [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
In [21]: df.groupby('date').apply(lambda x: x['issues'].value_counts()[:2])
Out[21]: 
date        
1     issue3    2
      issue1    2
2     issue2    1
      issue3    1
dtype: int64
```

*Note: this will arbitrarily pick if there is a tie.*

Comment: Sorry if I'm being a bit dense but that transformation on my stacked series doesn't seem to work as it is already grouped. If I try and use the original DataFrame, there is no 'size' column yet to sort on. From the Original DataFrame I did df.groupby(('date', 'issues')).size() to get the Series.

Comment: See above for the original data structure.

Comment: @Adam sorry you do this *before* the stack, I was going to add a line at the end saying then you stack, whoops! (Was just fixing the bug in pandas which required the index to be dropped :) )

Comment: Haha, no problem. I actually tried that but since there is no 'size' column in the original, I'm unsure of how to get it without stacking.

Comment: @Adam oh, I see! wait a sec

Comment: Size is just what I got from doing df.groupby(('date', 'issues')).size() on the original DataFrame. Just a count per issue, per month.

Comment: @Adam Ah thought so... the numbers don't match up with your original input (?), I think you can do this easier with value_counts, will append to answer.